# PHP - How to access and retrieve important data from a pop3 email account?

Tags: php, email, pop3

I am trying to create a php program that will check for the presence of any emails with a keyword in the subject line, then it will retrieve the contents of the email and pass it to a variable.

Can anyone provide me with some helpful information on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use imap protocol better, you can try the [imap functions of PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php)

```
<?php
    $imap = imap_open("{mail.yourserver.com:143}INBOX", "username", "password");
    $message_count = imap_num_msg($imap);

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $message_count; ++$i) {
        $header = imap_header($imap, $i);
        if (preg_match('#keyword#',$header['subject'])) {
             $body = imap_body($imap, $i);
             // your action here
        }
    }

    imap_close($imap);
?>
```

Comment: The PHP IMAP extension apparently also supports POP3.